# Initilized declared fields of subclass from super class

Tags: java, android, reflection

It is possible to initialize the value of the field?

I am able to get the fields from the subclass from the superclass

```
Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();


for(Field field : fields) {
    //I need to assign a value to every field depending on their type

    if(Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
        //Something like this
        field = (Integer) 100;
    } else if(MyObject.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
        //Something like this
        field = new MyObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry didn't search thoroughly

Comment: Hey, no need to be sorry :). enjoy your solution :)